# How can I connect OracleDB in Python by using SQLAcehmy

Tags: python, oracle11g, sqlalchemy

I tried to access the oracle DB by using SQLacehmy in python, but it didn't work.

```
from sqlalchemy
import create_engine
import cx_Oracle


DIALECT = 'oracle'
SQL_DRIVER = 'cx_oracle'
USERNAME = 'username'
PASSWORD = 'password'
HOST = '123.123.123.123'
PORT = 1521 
ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH = DIALECT + '+' + SQL_DRIVER + '://' + USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD + '@' + HOST + ':' + str(PORT) + '/

engine = create_engine(ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH)

#test query
import pandas as pd
test_df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM global_name', engine)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. Use the function `makedsn`:

```py
import cx_Oracle as ora
import sqlalchemy

def setup_db():
    user = "user_name"
    pwd = "password"
    dsn = ora.makedsn('some_ip', <some_port>, service_name="some_name")
    return sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        f"oracle+cx_oracle://{user}:{pwd}@{dsn}", 
        max_identifier_length=128, arraysize=5000
    )
```

Comment: I don't have the service name, just sid, how do I verify the connection?

Comment: @pakwai122 if you do not know the service name, do not use that parameter. Let's see if resolving to default value works.

Comment: no error, but how can I verify it's connecting the DB.

Comment: @pakwai122 try some query